# State changes triggered from separate devices with Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

**This behavior has been attributed to a Browsersync feature enabled by my yeoman generator.** 
Thanks for looking though!

EDIT: I did some more testing like this, and it seems all state changes leak. My question is now "How do I ensure each device only acts on the Angular 2 instance it's running?"

I've implemented a state change to hide and show a basic side panel menu. When the state is triggered, actions are performed as expected. The weirdness comes when I'm running the app on two devices at once.

After opening the app on my desktop and my phone, pressing the button to toggle the menu toggles it not just on the device I've interacting with, but also the other connected device. It seems to be a trigger issue as the panels do not sync their state.

Tl;dr Open menu on phone, it closes on desktop if it was already open. Open menu on phone, desktop menu opens if closed. This should not happen.

How do I prevent state changes from leaking like this?

sidepanel.ts

```
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, trigger, state, style, transition, animate} from '@angular/core';
import {Session} from '../services/session';

@Component({
  selector: 'sidepanel',
  template: require('./sidepanel.html'),
  styles: [ String(require('./sidepanel.scss')) ],
  animations: [
    trigger('panelWidthTrigger', [
      state('expanded', style({ left: '0' })),
      state('collapsed', style({ left: '-218px' })),
      transition('collapsed => expanded', animate('200ms ease-in')),
      transition('expanded => collapsed', animate('200ms 200ms ease-out'))
    ])]
  })
  export class Sidepanel {
    @Input() sessions: Session[];
    @Output('select') select = new EventEmitter();
    expanded = false;
    expandedState = 'expanded';

    constructor() {
    }

    newSession() {
      this.select.emit(new Session);
    }

    displaySession(session: Session) {
      this.select.emit(session);
    }

    toggleExpandedState() {
        this.expandedState = this.expanded ? 'collapsed' : 'expanded';
        this.expanded = !this.expanded;
    }

  }
```

sidepanel.html

```
<div class="side-panel" @panelWidthTrigger="expandedState">
  <div class="session-list-header">
    <h2>All Sessions<button (click)="toggleExpandedState()" class="session-list-button" ><span>&#9776;</span></button></h2>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li class="session-list-item" *ngFor="let session of sessions" (click)="displaySession(session)"><label class="session-list-item-title">{{session.name}}</label></li>
    <li class="session-list-item session-list-new" (click)="newSession()"><label class="session-list-item-title">New Session</label></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: As a note, I'm using Gulp, Webpack, and Browsersync to build. I used a yeoman generator to scaffold out the basic app which included default configs for these packages.

Comment: That's a browsersync feature and not related to Angular AFAIK.

Comment: I was just reading about Browsersync ghosting as a possible cause. Thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by my use of Browsersync without checking the configuration I used. Don't be like me, check your build configs when using new tools!